# database insertion in Laravel API

Tags: laravel, postgresql, crud, laravel-8, rest

While trying to do db insertion, I am getting Error - `SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"city\" of relation \"personal_details\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (12, abc, null, fff, dgh, null, 2021-06-28 08:34:53, 2021-06-28 08:34:53). (SQL: insert into \"personal_details\" (\"pincode\", \"district\", \"state\", \"updated_at\", \"created_at\") values (abc, fff, dgh, 2021-06-28 08:34:53, 2021-06-28 08:34:53) returning \"id\")",`  . I am a beginner and I don't know what's wrong with the below code. Also, i wanted  to return a json error msg, if the insertion failed in addition to the `$validator->fails()` condition, like the one i have commented in my code. Please help me if u have some suggestions.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\PersonalDetails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class PersonalDetailsAdmin extends Controller
{
    public function insert(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'pincode'    => 'required|string',
                'city'    => 'required|string',
                'district' => 'required|string',
                'state'    => 'required|string',
                'country'    => 'string',
            ]
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }


        $obj = new PersonalDetails();
        $obj->pincode=$request->pincode;
        $obj->district=$request->district;
        $obj->state=$request->state;
        $obj->save();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'success','data'=>$obj]);
    
       /* else{

            return response()->json(['message'=>'Failed'], 404);
        }*/
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PersonalDetails extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table='personal_details';
    protected $guarded=['id'];
}
```

Comment: $obj = new PersonalDetailsAdmin; to   $obj = new PersonalDetails;

Comment: @JohnLobo see the updated question. I got 1 other error when added the change th u said

Comment: add protected $guarded=['id'] and also pass city value

Comment: @JohnLobo see the updated question. added `protected $guarded=['id']` . in my db, all cells in `personal_details` table are filled with values. Nothing is null there. The error is related to the code only

Comment: @JohnLobo How to pass the city value? What do u meant to do actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of incorrect namespaces. In `PersonalDetails` file `namespace App\Models;` means that `PersonalDetails` model/file is store in the path `App\Models;` however in your `PersonalDetailsAdmin` controller you are trying to import `PersonalDetails` model from `App\Http\Models\PersonalDetails;` Reference your files correctly and everything should be fine.

Also instantiate the model properly like this `$obj = new PersonalDetails();`

Comment: please be more specific. what all changes shall i make here?

Comment: Assuming that `PersonalDetails` file is stored in this path `App\Models;` in your controller change this line `use App\Http\Models\PersonalDetails;` => `App\Models\PersonalDetails;` then `$obj = new PersonalDetailsAdmin;` => `$obj = new PersonalDetails();`

Comment: see the updated question.I have made the changes u said. it now has the error -`   SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"city\" of relation \"personal_details\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (12, abc, null, fff, dgh, null, 2021-06-28 08:34:53, 2021-06-28 08:34:53). (SQL: insert into \"personal_details\" (\"pincode\", \"district\", \"state\", \"updated_at\", \"created_at\") values (abc, fff, dgh, 2021-06-28 08:34:53, 2021-06-28 08:34:53) returning \"id\")
`

Comment: Now its about the migrations file if you are not sure about the table columns make them `nullable`. For example in `yyyy_mm_dd_xxxxxx_create_personal_details_table.php` decorate each column with nullable like this `$table->string('column_name')->nullable();` After making these changes run `php artisan migrate:rollback` then `php artisan migrate`

Comment: why `rollback`? why not `migrate:fresh`?

Comment: Use `migrate:refresh` is you want to rollback and migrate all migrations. `rollback` will rollback your migrations per batch. If you are still in development stage they save the same purpose

Comment: All the cells in my `personal_details` table are filled with values. Nothing  is null there. The error is related to the code only.

Comment: How do you mean? Can you please send what your migrations look like and table contents. Also try not to change the question, so that answers remain relevant to the initial post.

Comment: migration structure- `Schema::create('personal_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('pincode');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('district');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->timestamps();
        });`  - i have done seeding. So i have kept dummy data in db. Therefore, I don't have any empty cell in db

Comment: Looks fine to me, Im not seeing any nullable columns. Just make sure when you create a record provide all required values `$obj->pincode="some_pin"`, `$obj->city="some_city"` etc. What's your error now?

Comment: error is same - `SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column \"city\" of relation \"personal_details\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL: Failing row contains (12, abc, null, fff, dgh, null, 2021-06-28 08:34:53, 2021-06-28 08:34:53). (SQL: insert into \"personal_details\" (\"pincode\", \"district\", \"state\", \"updated_at\", \"created_at\") values (abc, fff, dgh, 2021-06-28 08:34:53, 2021-06-28 08:34:53) returning \"id\") `

Comment: Its because you are not providing all the column values mate. In your case you are creating a record with `pincode,district,state` but your migrations defined the table to have `city,country` also. provide city and country also.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I added `city` `country` fields too in the input. still the same error persists

Comment: Kindly reply. This is my present error - `SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"city\" of relation \"personal_details\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (65, aa, null, sssssss, aaaaaaa, null, 2021-06-28 10:18:57, 2021-06-28 10:18:57). (SQL: insert into \"personal_details\" (\"pincode\", \"district\", \"state\", \"updated_at\", \"created_at\") values (aa, sssssss, aaaaaaa, 2021-06-28 10:18:57, 2021-06-28 10:18:57) returning \"id\")`

Comment: Will it because i am not inserting a value to the `id` column ? or will it set the id automatically?

Comment: Thank u. Finaal the errors got resolved.However, my question has one other portion too - "How to give an error msg if insertion failed." Please tell me if u know the answer

Comment: @MG the error `ERROR:null value in column some_column of relation some_table violates not-null constraint` means you are trying to insert a null value in a non-nullable cell so always provide real value. You can surround the insertion part in a try ... catch block, where you provide error message in the catch clause. **But best practice is to use validation** `$validated = $request->validate(['column_name' => 'required',...others]);` [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)